How to cache large test fixture files for GitLab CI pipeline and whats best approach?
I have a python script which runs on command line interface. This script contains some python unit tests for the functions in the script. The repository I created on Gitlab and my Gitlab runner is hosted on openstack cloud linux instance which has 16GB-RAM/100GB-HDD/8-CPU.
Now, when the test job is running on the runner it has a small bash script which downloads two files of size 4GB and 1.2GB. Everytime I create Pull request gitlab CI pipeline downloads these two files takes longer to finish the job. Initially I thought of caching these two files so, when everytime when I push the code and create PR or someone else does it will not download these two files and instead will use cached files.
Here is my basic project structure and .gitlab-ci.yml configuration:
.
└── myproject/
    ├── .githookes/
    ├── fixture_data/
    │   ├── fixture_data_1.txt  # This is size of 5GB
    │   └── fixture_data_2.txt  # This is size of 1.2GB
    ├── src/
    │   └── main_script.py
    ├── tests/
    │   └── test_test_script.py
    ├── download_fixture_data.sh
    ├── .gitlab-ci.yml
    ├── .gitignore
    └── Dockerfile

And .gitlab-ci.yml.
stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - fixture_data/fixture_data_1.txt
    - fixture_data/fixture_data_2.txt

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:23.0.6
  tags:
    - openstack-autoscale
    - autoscale-docker-in-docker
  services:
    - name: docker:23.0.6-dind
  script:
    - make build-docker
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
    - changes:
      - requirements.txt
      - Dockerfile

test:
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
  stage: test
  tags:
    - openstack-autoscale
    - autoscale-docker-in-docker
  before_script:
    - ./download_fixture_data.sh
  cache:
    key: ${{ path }}  # Inherit cache key from the root of the pipeline
    paths:
      - fixture_data/fixture_data_1.txt
      - fixture_data/fixture_data_2.txt
  script:
    - docker run my_image pip install -r requirements.txt
    - docker run my_image python -m unittest

download_fixture_data.sh:
#!/bin/bash

mkdir fixture_data

curl -o fixture_data/fixture_data_1.txt https://some-url-to-download-fixture_data_1.txt
curl -o fixture_data/fixture_data_2.txt https://some-url-to-download-fixture_data_2.txt

With above configuration gitlab pipeline and jobs are running fine but it is not doing what it supposed to do, that is caching two files for next PR pipeline run.
I am not sure why it is not working and whether which approach to follow when caching files for gitlab ci pipeline. I have three people including me working on the same repo. If you could guide me or possibly could tell what am I missing or wrong here, would be great!
